# Implement Swipe Pages in Android

Tags: android

I am making an application similar to a Powerpoint slideshow where user moves to next slide by swiping to left.

I am aware of making swipe pageviews using Viewpager and Fragments. But my application has hundreds of slides and I would not prefer to make those many fragments for each of my slide.

What I am planning is that I would have a single layout with say 10 textviews and then show each textview as a slide on the screen. On swiping on the screen, the next textview will appear.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: And why you don't go with the `ViewPager`?

Comment: Yeah, but won't it require making fragments ?

Comment: Yes but would be easier to manage/implement

Comment: but I have hundreds of slides to show. How can I make hundreds of fragments ?

Comment: "won't it require making fragments ?" -- no, `ViewPager` knows nothing about fragments, and you are welcome to make a `PagerAdapter` that does not use fragments. Beyond that, though, you have not explained why you think that using fragments is bad. I publish [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android) as an APK, using a `ViewPager` with `WebViewFragment`, one fragment per chapter. At 193 chapters in the current edition, my book is as big as your proposed app, perhaps bigger depending on how you measure it.

Comment: So CommonsWare, you think making more than 200 fragments is not a bad idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use gestureListeners to determine a swipe and then use animation to 'show' a swipe. That way you don't even need 10 textviews. Depending on the visual effect yoi want you can probably do with 1 or 2 textViews.

If you need more info, please comment, I'll try to post something once I'm back at my desk.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will load my information in those textviews. For example, if I want to show 26 letters of English Alphabet, then total 26 textviews will hold those 26 letters. The app will start with first textview on the screen and on swiping it will move to the next.  So, the total slides will be 26.

Answer (score 0):

Why should you use [HorizontalScrollView](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/horizontalscrollview/android-horizontalscrollview-example/)

this will be easy to use and fullfill your requirement.